# Changing style of newly created DIv using Jquery in each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am fetching the data from xml file and calling a some function for that data,
all this procedure is inside `each(function()`)

my code is

```
$(my_xml_data). find (any_node_from_that_xml) . each(function()
{
  any_variable = $(this).attr ( "any_attribute" );
  draw_a_graph (any_variable, "id_of_DIV_inwhich_graph_gonna_draw");
}
```

now i want each graph should be drew inside a "newDIV" in each iteration. and this "new_DIV" must be 50px "right" from old one (means i can edit "left" attr of new div's style ).

pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of positioning it via JS, you could actually have a CSS class for each DIV (on which the graph is drawn). In your CSS file or `<style></style>` section, you can have something like:

```
div.graph_div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  /* set other styles as needed */
}
```

And in your code you can do something like:

```
var parentDiv = $('#id_of_your_parent_div')
$(my_xml_data). find (any_node_from_that_xml) . each(function()
{
  any_variable = $(this).attr ( "any_attribute" );
  var graphDiv = $('<div class="graph_div"></div>').appendTo(parentDiv);
  draw_a_graph (any_variable, graphDiv);
}
```

Note that the above `draw_a_graph` function takes an element as argument and not an ID. If changing the signature of `draw_a_graph` is not possible, then you can do something like:

```
var parentDiv = $('#id_of_your_parent_div')
$(my_xml_data). find (any_node_from_that_xml) . each(function()
{
  var divID = 'graph_'+(Math.random()*1000);
  var graphDiv = $('<div id="'+divID+'" class="graph_div"></div>').appendTo(parentDiv);
  draw_a_graph (any_variable, divID);
}
```

Comment: Thanx Dude it helped me a lot to draw graph... but still they get draw on same location. i mean if i define left margin 50 px all graph get draw on 50px away from left on each other(overwrite)... not 50 px away from each other
can u help on this ?

Comment: I did a sample fiddle to demonstrate the margin-left styling method. http://jsfiddle.net/VBtVG/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want each successive div to be 50px more to the left...

```
$(my_xml_data). find (any_node_from_that_xml) . each(function(i,elem)
{
  any_variable = $(this).attr ( "any_attribute" );
  draw_a_graph (any_variable, "id_of_DIV_inwhich_graph_gonna_draw");
  var left = 50 * i; // i is the index of your current node
  $("#id_of_DIV_inwhich_graph_gonna_draw").css('left', left+'px');
}
```

Comment: actually, i want to change the id of that "id_of_DIV_inwhich_graph_gonna_draw" in each iteration and append it to "ParentDIV".